# How to monitor SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, view, timer-jobs

I have a SharePoint list with the following fields.

**1.Event Name**

**2. Hit Count**

I want to monitor this list by the hit count for events on a yearly basis. What is the best approach I could take?

Options: 
Create views for each year.

**EDIT:**

Adding a field for each year, on the 1st of January will populate the number of fields in the list. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Which sharepoint version ? How many item per year ? What you have tried ?

Comment: It is continuously adding the count, regardless of the date. I want a way to track it by year. SharePoint 2013.